# how to fix Error return url error after payment in magento 2

Tags: magento2

After the payment process this error coming on magento 2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Zend\Log\Logger::error() in /home/shubh/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php:93 Stack trace: #0 /home/shubh/public_html/app/code/Magento/Ccavenuepay/Model/Order/OrderEmail.php(57): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender->checkAndSend(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor)) #1 /home/shubh/public_html/app/code/Magento/Ccavenuepay/Model/Ccavenuepay.php(614): Magento\Ccavenuepay\Model\Order\OrderEmail->send(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor), false, true) #2 /home/shubh/public_html/app/code/Magento/Ccavenuepay/Controller/Ccavenuepay/ReturnUrl.php(153): Magento\Ccavenuepay\Model\Ccavenuepay->getCcavenueOrderMailSender(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor)) #3 /home/shubh/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): Magento\Ccavenuepay\Controller\Ccavenuepay\ReturnUrl->execute() #4 /home/shubh/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action in /home/shubh/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php on line 93

Answer (score 0):

It seems module "Ccavenuepay" can't send emails, please check email configuration.

Comment: where we check the email configuration?